# react native cli on linuxmint19 for android installation giving errrors

Tags: android, react-native, npm

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-112-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect ENETUNREACH 2606:4700::6810:1a23:80
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jean/npm-debug.log

And i have many node versions installed on my computer how do i uninstall and fix it

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was an issue with internet or something got resolved on its on.